# How to effectively process lot of objects on a list on server side

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, scalability

I have a List which contains a lot of objects.
The problem is that i have to process these objects (process includes cloning, deep copy, and making DB calls, running business logic etc etc.

Doing this in a normal fashion, first come first serve is really time consuming and in a web application , this generally results in transaction timeouts at the server side (as this processing is anync from client perspective).

How do i process those objects so as to take minimal time and not overload the DB.

I'm using java 7 on server environment.

I'm already using a messaging solution , rabbitmq, which gets me the item and its quantity. problem occurs when i try to deep copy items to mimic real items (business logic every item should be uniquely processed) and save them to DB.

Comment: i'm thinking of using java's executor service for running this bulk request  in multiple threads..

Comment: Though am not sure what is cloning and deep copy for. But, some keywords for you to think your solution upon: batches, thread pools, connection pool

Comment: if its possible to do it asynchronous, you can make use of queues & JMS

Comment: In Java8 you could consider parallel streams, which are much simpler than executors.

Comment: i'm already using a messaging solution , rabbitmq, which gets me the item and its quantity.
problem occurs when i try to deep copy items to mimic real items (business logic every item should be uniquely processed) and save them to DB.

Comment: You can use Spring batch,Executor, Scheduler in Spring framework with transaction facility but before pushing data to database you have to make changes in value object on the basis of you requirement and also the limit of the database object which you want to save in database.All are valid if your requirement is asynchronous means one item's state won't change the other's item state as all above solutions works in asynchronous way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After another round of profiling i found that the bottle neck was the DB connection pool having low number of max connections.
I deduced this by running the same transaction without db thread pool and it went perfectly well and completed without any exception.
However combining the previous approach i.e. managing an ABQ and light commits with HA DB will be the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

After some discussions, the viable solution is using a ABQ (array blocking queues) which is processed by a pool of threads.
Following are the thought out benefits:

1) we wont have to manage the 3rd party queues created e.g. rabbitmq
2) At any point in time the blocking queue wont have all the items to be processed as the consumer threads will be simultaneously processing them, so it will leave lesser memory footprint.

@cody123 i'm using spring batch for retry mechanisms in this case.